# What would be the best way to handle a system with multiple user types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, roles, user-management

I've been given the task of updating an asp system to MVC3. My main issue is that the current system has 2 different kinds of user, each user has their own user table, and in the current asp site, each user is defined by a number of different session held variables.

Because other systems use the two different user tables, I can't merge them. So what would be the best way forward?

I initally thought about keeping them seperate in the system; having a class type for each user which holds the seperate variables mirrored from their asp counterpart. On login, I could push user type to userdata in the auth cookie, then create an extension method on the IPrincipal to return the user type when required.

This feels a bit of a hack, and as the users will be viewing the same pages, there would be a lot of duplication of code.

Would it be better to create some form of facade before the user repository which would attach a role to a common user object which would identify the user type in the system? I could then check this role and pull out the data, that used to be stored in session variables, when needed.

Comment: If *I* was building this application from the ground up, i'd differentiate user type by role. With this in mind, I've created an anticorruption class between the User builder and reps. This injects/removes a role (id of 0) to distinguish user type. In future, the client hopes to merge tables, so this seemed the most sensible way forward for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was building this application from the ground up, i'd differentiate user type by role. With this in mind, I've created an anticorruption class between the User builder and reps. This injects/removes a role (id of 0) to distinguish user type. In future, the client hopes to merge tables, so this seemed the most sensible way forward for now.

Answer (score 0):

If I would given a chance to do this I would do it in following way:

1. Implement asp.net membership provider and import all users into it.
2. Create two different roles for user types
3. Use profile provider to store additional properties from user type tables.

This way, you can use combination of role and profile to handle any situation related to authorization and restriction.

Comment: Hi Prashant, I'd ideally love to do this, but I need to use the existing tables and can't modify them in any way - this is a stipulation of the contract.

Comment: Ok then you need a little trick to extend providers to read data from your tables. I am sure they are extensible and you can get some good examples of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would define an interface with methods common to both users, and have both user types implement the interface. So, if you have something like:

```
interface IUser { bool CanViewPage1(); }
class UserType1 : IUser { }
class UserType2 : IUser { }

Session["user"] = new UserType1();
```

Then you can do:

```
var user = (IUser)Session["user"];
```

For common operations:

```
if (user.CanViewPage1())
{ 
   ...
}
```

and for operations where you need the user object:

```
bool CanViewPage2(IUser user)
{
   if(user is UserType1)
   {
       var ut1 = (UserType1)user;
       ...
   } else if (user is UserType2)
   {
       var ut2 = (UserType2)user;
       ...
   }
}
```

The last part can be done via extension methods as well, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest to use WIF with custom simple STS server and use claims for user types. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx

And for checking this stuff - use custom attribute, or simple - Identity.HasClaim("someclaim name or type").

Also this will standartize your approach for authentication/authorization, which can save some time later=)